# Models and ModelForms: needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, django-forms, save, django-orm

I'm using a Django Model with some many-to-many fields. I'm also using a ModelForm to generate the associated form. It is my understanding that, provided nothing else is overridden, Django should be able to handle many-to-many fields being saved in the ModelForm?

For me, attempting to do this is causing this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /cameramodel/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 383, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 403, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1188, in full_clean
    self.clean()
  File "./schema/models.py", line 1439, in clean
    if self.metering_modes is True:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 527, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 838, in __init__
    raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
ValueError: "<CameraModel: Canon Canonflex R2000>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

So I checked out the docs and it seems like I need to override the `save` method in the `ModelForm`. So I did this:

```
class CameraModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CameraModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        form = super(CameraModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.save_m2m()
        return form
```

and instead I'm getting a different error:

```
TypeError at /cameramodel/create/
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/cameramodel/create/
Django Version: 2.2.12
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'
Exception Location: /home/jonathan/git/camerahub/schema/models.py in save, line 1397
```

and `models.py:1397` is actually an overridden Model save to add a slug field:

```
class CameraModel(models.Model):
# other stuff here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            custom_slugify_unique = UniqueSlugify(
                unique_check=cameramodel_check, to_lower=True)
            self.slug = custom_slugify_unique("{} {} {}".format(
                self.manufacturer.name, self.model, str(self.disambiguation or '')))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For what it's worth, I am using many-to-many fields in some other models and I'm not seeing a problem with them. I'm a Python/Django beginner though and I'm pretty stuck on this one because simply following the advice on a million other posts like this one hasn't helped me. Grateful for any advice or code snippets anyone can offer.

If anyone needs more context, the whole project is open source and this branch is available here: https://github.com/djjudas21/camerahub/tree/278c_m2m_error

Answer (score 0):

If you override, the `save` method, it means you want to make some checks/changes before saving your form. I would instead do:

```
def save(self):
      form = super(CameraModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
      if ...: # some condition on form values
          form.save() # remove the commit here
          form.save_m2m()
      return form
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried this but it fails with `AttributeError at /cameramodel/create/ 'CameraModel' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'`. I believe it is because the `save_m2m` attribute is only defined if `form` has previously been saved with `commit=False`